# Using google maps from a .NET desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps

A interesting thread at : http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/252531 
Apparently google has asked the developer to remove support for google maps from the open source API because it uses undocumented methods (which are obviously quite openly documented by third parties all over the internet).

Two questions:

Is there no legal way to make google maps applications without using the provided javascript / flex apis?

If so aren't there a lot of applications out there that do this illegally? (even mapinfo 10 has google maps support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my non-legal background, with some small experience working with the Google API, and google itself, I would say:

1. No there is no legal way, unless you can get Google to agree, which they won't.
2. Yes there are lots of applications which do this illegally, however there are also some which do so legally.

Answer (score 4):

PS: Found the documentation for this : http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

> 10.1 Restrictions on How You May Use the Maps API(s). Except as explicitly
>   permitted in Section 8 (Licenses from
>   Google to You) or the Maps APIs
>   Documentation, you must not (nor may
>   you permit anyone else to) do any of
>   the following:
>
> - 10.1.1. General Restrictions.
>
> (a) No Access to Maps API(s) except through the Service. You must not
>   access or use the Maps API(s) or any
>   Content through any technology or
>   means other than those provided in the
>   Service, or through other explicitly
>   authorized means Google may designate.
>   For example, you must not access map
>   tiles or imagery through interfaces or
>   channels (including undocumented
>   Google interfaces) other than the Maps
>   API(s).

So any application that doesn't either call the javascript / flex / webservice api is illegally using it UNLESS google approved the application (like the iphone maps application). This is bad for small time developers.

Comment: But here's the thing showing source code to do this is not illegal! using that source code is :) so feel free to develop such apis!

Comment: After reading the topic you initially pointed to, I don't believe the quoted terms apply.  You are NOT going through the API when you directly access the tiles, as the GMap.NET project does.  Therefore, you can't be violating their API terms of use in my eyes, because you never agreed to it or used it.