# C# Winform App - Display a map

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps

i was wondering how hard it would be using a winforms application to pass a postcode to some service and then return a map which i can display to the user ? Does anyone know of a service to do this?

I am making an app to display the local pubs in my area for fun :D

Comment: Is a webbrowser control an option?

Comment: well i guess it is, but you cant really display a neat little map in the corner can you? the user ends up having to scroll a lot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its not to hard to accomplish.. see this link http://linqtotwitter.wordpress.com/2005/10/05/google-maps-api-in-c/

[Win Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/GMapNET.aspx)

[Another good link about offline G-Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453885/using-google-maps-from-a-net-desktop-application)

Comment: can this be used with winforms, seeing as its asp?